# Loud grind like noise and starts gettin hot what could it be

Tags: engine, noise, overheating, pontiac, g6

2007 Pontiac g6
Just put antifreeze in for the winter. It's making a loud grinding like noise and starts getting hot. It lasts for a minute or two then stops for a minute and does it again

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Was the change in coolant just a regular maintenance item for you? Did you use DEXCOOL? Was there any noise before you had this done? Did you change it yourself? Is the coolant level up to where it should be?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The way I understand it, the car starts to overheat - then there's loud noise and the temperature goes down. The noise is periodic. Is this correct?

This is likely related to the cooling fan - either the shroud is bent, foreign object stuck between the fan and the shroud, or the fan bearing is gone.